# pymunk - Tripping Segment

Tags: pymunk

I am trying to do the following:

Vertical line segment (with mass) moving forward (@ fixed velocity) on the ground (no friction), tripping over a point (rock) on the ground. I am looking for the segment point in contact with the ground to stop forward velocity and have the segment tip over that point taking into consideration conservation of momentum of the evenly distributed mass.

I have honestly tried for hours trying to figure this out. The closet I get is a collision but the segment does not tip, the whole thing just instantly stops and the top of the segment slowly start tipping backwards.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a small example of what you have tried? Then it will be easier to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the elasticity of the objects to 1.